.NET Maui DataBinding does not update Entry or Label
Hello I am trying to use databinding in .NET Maui and ran into a strange problem
I have an Entry, where I want the user to be able to clear it if he press a button in my ViewModel.
When i press the Button to clear the Customer.CustomerName the Property does not update, not until i navigate to another page in the app.
I don't understand why its not updating when the property is already implementing INotifyPropertyChanged
XAML
<Entry 
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    FontAttributes="Bold"
    FontSize="Large"
    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
    Placeholder="Name"
    Text="{Binding CurrentCustomer.CustomerName}"
    VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
<Button 
    Grid.Row="7"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Margin="2"
    Command="{Binding ClearUserInfo}"
    Text="Clear User Information" />

<!--  Test to show reset value  -->
<Label
    Grid.Row="7"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Margin="2"
    Text="{Binding CurrentCustomer.CustomerName}" />

ViewModel
[AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
public class CustomerViewModel
{     
    public Customer CurrentCustomer { get; set; } = new Customer();

    public ICommand ClearUserInfo =>
       new Command(() =>
       {
           ClearUserInputs();        
       });

    private void ClearUserInputs()
    {
        CurrentCustomer.CustomerName = "Set string to empty";
        // CurrentCustomer.CustomerName = string.Empty;
    }
}

public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerAddress { get; set; }
    public string CustomerPhone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}


Please post the code for Customer

Hi. I edited my original post with the Code For Customer

Your Customer model is not observable. That's why the UI doesn't update.

Hey I am a bit new. but if CurrentCustomer in the ViewModel is implementing INotifyPropertyChanged do I still have to make the customer Model observable also in the model class ?. Because It does work when I navigate to another page and come back to the page i went from, then it is indeed updated

CustomerName must be observable because that is the property that you are updating

You either need to make your Customer model observable or you can also assign a new value to CurrentCustomer.
Child properties do not become observable just because the parent is used as an observable property. Instead, each property that is supposed to be observable must invoke the PropertyChanged event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, in Fody-terms this would then look like:
[AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerAddress { get; set; }
    public string CustomerPhone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}


Hey god man. Thanks a lot for your help, and very clear explanation. Now it works :-)
